# MSAL4J Office365 PublicClientApplication -> UsernaemPasswordParameters still available after End of Basic Authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices, access-token, exchange-basicauth

According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/

the basic authentication of office365 will not be possible after october.

Will the PublicClientApplicationFlow (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens-with-username-and-password) with UsernamePasswordParameters for aquiring the accesstoken still be possible (although I know it is not recommended)? I guess that way will still be open to acquire the token, right?